# Recover multibit.wallet data

Tags: wallet, multibit

I just recieved a payment sent me bitcoins on my old multibit 0.5.18 wallet. I opened it up and didn't see it, so I refreshed the blockchain. When I did this my wallet crashed. When I started it back up I got a message saying could not load the wallet. I went to the directory $HOME/MultiBit/multibit-data/wallet-unenc-backup to load a backup and got the same message.

Is their a way I can get the private keys out of the multibit.wallet file so I can build an unencrypted.key file. So I can send the bitcoins to my new Multibit HD wallet?

Comment: @Christopher Gurnee is the expert on this. He maintains btcrecover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the wallet encrypted or not ?
If encrypted, then you will have some automatically generated exports of your private keys in the $HOME/MultiBit/multibit-data/key-backup directory. They are encrypted with your wallet password.

You can create a new wallet and import this file using Tools | Import private key.

There are also rolling backups (essentially old versions of your wallet) in the directory rolling-backup that you can open using File | Open wallet

Comment: Not encrypted. Trying to imported some of the unencrypted wallet backups using the Tools Import method I will let you know how it goes. And vote you up